# Combining a filter within a map

Tags: scala, dictionary, filter

I have a list which I am combining to a map in this way, by calling the respective value calculation function. I am using `collection.breakout` to avoid creating unnecessary intermediate collections since what I am doing is a bit combinatorial, and every little bit of saved iterations helps.

I need to filter out certain tuples from the map, in my case where the value is less than 0. Is it possible to add this to the map itself rather than doing a `filter` afterwards (thus iterating once again)?

```
val myMap: Map[Key, Int] = keyList.map(key => key -> computeValue(key))(collection.breakOut)

val myFilteredMap  = myMap.filter(_._2 >= 0)
```

In other words I wish to obtain the second map ideally at one go, so ideally in the first call to `map()` I filter out the tuples I don't want. Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this with a `foldLeft`:

```
keyList.foldLeft( Map[Key,Int]() ) {
  (map, key) => 
    val value = computeValue(key)
    if ( value >= 0 ) {
      map + (key -> value)
    } else {
      map
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! A bit lengthy, but seems sufficiently clean.

Answer (score 4):

It would probably be best to do a flatMap:

```
import collection.breakOut
type Key = Int
val keyList = List(-1,0,1,2,3)
def computeValue(i: Int) = i*2

val myMap: Map[Key, Int] = 
  keyList.flatMap { key => 
    val v = computeValue(key)
    if (v >= 0) Some(key -> v)
    else None
  }(breakOut)
```

You can use `collect`

```
val myMap: Map[Key, Int] = 
  keyList.collect { 
    case key if computeValue(key) >= 0 => key -> computeValue(key) 
  }(breakOut)
```

But that requires re-computing `computeValue(key)`, which is silly.  Collect is better when you filter *then* map.

Or make your own method!:

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.TraversableLike

implicit class EnrichedWithMapfilter[A, Repr](val self: TraversableLike[A, Repr]) extends AnyVal {
  def maptofilter[B, That](f: A => B)(p: B => Boolean)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, (A, B), That]): That = {
    val b = bf(self.asInstanceOf[Repr])
    b.sizeHint(self)
    for (x <- self) { 
      val v = f(x)
      if (p(v))
        b += x -> f(x)
    }
    b.result
  }
}

val myMap: Map[Key, Int] = keyList.maptofilter(computeValue)(_ >= 0)(breakOut)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is your flatMap option faster or better in any way than the method suggested by Mauricio Linhares?

Comment: The flatMap solution is conceptually cleaner to me than folding since it hides the details of actually building the new collection.  As for speed, I don't know.

Comment: OK thanks. I am still a bit uncomfortable with hiding too much (still new to Scala). The other method is a bit clearer to me what's happening. Still +1 for your detailed explanations.